# Customize the apex class in Cloudcraze to extend functionality

Tags: apex, b2b-commerce, cloudcraze

Cloudcraze is a managed package and hence we cannot modify the code, but I was reading that we can extend it, but did not understood if we can really extend a class functionality.

The cancellation functionality in cloud craze order needed some enhancement as per the business requirements and Salesforce support told that there are currently two methods that should be considered when implementing an extension to perform this task:

- authCancel() method - Used to verify an order can be canceled
- cancel() method - The cancel method changes the status of an order to "canceled" after checking with the ccrz.ccAPIOrder.authCancel method. The Cybersource API call for killing the AUTH would need to be placed into this method.

Here's a link to our documentation regarding ccApiOrder and more details about what each of those methods do: ccrz.ccApiOrder

So I create a new class as

```
public class ccLogicOrderCancelExtention extends ccLogicOrderCancel {

    public Map<String,Object> process(Map<String,Object> inpData) {

  }

}
```

This gives me an error to extend as

```
Invalid type: ccLogicOrderCancel
```

I feel I am missing something basic here as extension functionality is not working. Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

You have to reference all types, interfaces, and other identifiers that are part of a managed package with the appropriate namespace prefix.

If the type `ccLogicOrderCancel` is part of the managed package with namespace `ccrz`, you must refer to it as `ccrz.ccLogicOrderCancel`.

This type of namespacing applies to all Apex identifiers. Schema elements are namespaced with a `__` separator, e.g., `MyNS__Some_Object__c`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```java
public override Map<String,Object> process(Map<String,Object> inpData) {

}
```